# What is the typical use case of Spring Application Events?

Tags: spring, events, reactive-programming

There is an amazing mechanism is spring: Spring Application Events, I see it helps to build loosely coupled application, implement observer pattern, reactor pattern.

My question is, what is the trigger in Spring application architecture when Spring Application Events is absolutely inevitable? Actually any application classes relationship can be build using events only as well as using class associations and  hierarchy only (i'm talking about monolith service now).

May be it's more architectural question, but what is the threshold when it's need to consider events between objects inside a spring application?

Could it be definitely seen the cases when Spring Application Events absolutely needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Spring Security pushes events on certain event occurrences. [See list of events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/package-summary.html)
- In some cases, it's much better to push message instead invoke a method in a classical way. Eg if you need to invoke the same function I multiple places in the code, just to notify another object.
- It allows us to build a system which utilizes event-driven architecture. [Read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)
- Helps in solving [a producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)
- Send emails by pushing event object to `ApplicationEventPublisher` [See Spring Higher-Order Components and @EnableEmailSending](https://github.com/jpomykala/spring-higher-order-components#enableemailsending)